# Connection pooling showing INACTIVE connections in database

Tags: java, hashtable, datasource, connection-pooling

I am using connection pooling with **SharedPoolDataSource** in struts application. Application user pass the Connection parameters dynamically through user interface. I am creating object of **DriverAdapterCPDS** and assigning it to **SharedPoolDataSource** obj props.

```
SharedPoolDataSource tds = new SharedPoolDataSource();
            tds.setConnectionPoolDataSource(cpds);
            tds.setMaxActive(5);
            tds.setMaxIdle(2);
            tds.setMaxWait(50);
            tds.setTestOnBorrow(true);
            tds.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
```

I am storing it in the hashtable of DBUtil class with company name as key. Like this app user assigns lot of database details associated with each company.

```
dbUtil.DSht.put(comp, tds);
```

From the another program (Swing App) user send company name. So that I need to get the datasource object respective to company and execute queries on that database which are assigned to the user. And return result as object.

So I wrote a function like this

```
public static Connection getClientConnection(String comp){
    Connection con = null;
    try{
        if(!dbUtil.DSht.contains(comp)){
            loadClientDataSource(comp);
        }
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)dbUtil.DSht.get(comp);            
        Idle:"+bds.getNumIdle());
        con = ds.getConnection();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new DBUtilException("Unable to get the client connection object. Cause: "+e.getMessage());
    }        
    return con;
}
```

to close the database connection

```
public static void closeConnection(Connection con){
    try{
        if(con != null)
            con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

I am calling this **closeConnection** function in finally block

```
try{
        con = DBUtil.getClientConnection(comp);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);            
        pstmt.executeQuery();
    }catch(SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        throw new QueryException("Unable to add query. Cause: "+sqle.getMessage());
    }finally{
        DBUtil.closeStatement(pstmt);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
    }
```

Is there any problem of using the connection pooling? After using this application database showing lot of **INACTIVE** connections associated to my computer. Even after closing the connection it is showing like that. I set only 2 MAXIDLE connections for the database.

What is the problem? Why it is showing that much of **INACTIVE** connections? Is there any problem if we put datasource in hashtable?

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry about it, having session in INACTIVE state is not a anomaly. Check http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:914029001168

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, How should i know how may connections i am holding through java?

Comment: It depends on your connection pool configuration, usage of connections  by your application and session parameters like maximum inactive time for a session.

Comment: I found a problem while getting the datasource from hashtable in getConnection() method. It should be dbUtil.DSht.containsKey(compcode) instead of dbUtil.DSht.contains(compcode).